# Is ReplicaSet self-healing?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, replicaset

I know many Kubernetes objects are self-healing and many are not.

In the case of ReplicaSet, I searched online a lot but could not find a direct answer on whether ReplicaSet is self-healing or not. Can anyone please share?

Comment: What do you mean by "self-healing" here?  What's an example of an object that is, and what mechanism ensures that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ReplicaSets themselves are not self-healing, hence if you delete a ReplicaSet then Kubernetes won’t automatically create a new ReplicaSet.

But ReplicaSet makes sure that Pods get self-healed, hence if you delete a Deployment's Pod then ReplicaSet will ensure that another Pod gets created.

Answer (score 2):

As per the [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicaset/#deleting-a-replicaset-and-its-pods), once you delete the ReplicaSet, GC will garbage collect it along with all its pods, so ReplicaSet doesn't self-heal.